# Pinning a specific PPA from Launchpad

Tags: apt, package-management, ppa, pinning

I'm attempting to raise the priority of packages from the Ondrej PHP PPA from `500` to `1000`.

I attempted this:

```
Package: *
Pin: o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php,a=bionic,n=bionic,c=main,b=amd64
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

But `apt` did not understand the Pin directive

> ```
> default: Did not understand pin type o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php,a=bionic,n=bionic,c=main,b=amd64
> ```

I've found documentation that allows me to do this for top level domain origins for example i succesfully pinned nodesource using:

```
Package: *
Pin: origin deb.nodesource.com
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

But not specific PPA's. How would I pin a *specific* PPA?

Comment: Likewise `LP-PPA-ondrej-php,a=bionic,n=bionic` did not work

Comment: This doc ended up being very useful https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/02/set-package-ppa-apt-repository-priority-ubuntu/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use snippet below:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/preferences.d/pin-ppa
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php
Pin-Priority: 1337
EOF
```

Answer (score 7):

I figured it out:

```
Package: *
Pin: release o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

`Pin: release o=<ppaname>` where the ppa name is found by running `apt-cache policy` and inspecting the output:

```
1001 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
     release v=18.04,o=LP-PPA-ondrej-php,a=bionic,n=bionic,l=***** The main PPA for supported PHP versions with many PECL extensions *****,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
```